# Using Ajax, change options of select 2 if select 1 changes it's value

Tags: jquery

So I have two selects. Idea is, when user chooses his option in the first select, based on that, the values of the second select changes, and the values come from a different file using Ajax.

```
<select id="subject"></select>
<select id="theme"></select>
```

I tried this, which is not working. Any help ?

```
$('#subject').change(function(
    var v = $(this).val();
    getTheme(v);
});
function getTheme(id) {
   alert(id);
   $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: 'gettheme.php',
     data: "q=" + id, 
     success: function(data) {
          $('#theme').html(data);
     }
   });
}
```

Comment: do you get any errors in the console? Is your php script returning anything (check in the Net tab of Chrome inspector or log the response)? Is that response already formatted into `option` elements?

Comment: What part of it is not working? Also, you're missing values, var v = $(this).val(); is always empty. Element id is not value.

Comment: @BadrHari it seems that the function getTheme is not working, I am not even getting the alert, or its not loading the values of gettheme.php?q=id to the second select :)

PeterVR I have not found any errror yet.

Comment: @Jeremy You mistyped the function syntax use as as function(){ and check my answer

Comment: You really should learn how to work with your browsers developer tools, cause that missing bracket @Jeremy spotted would definitely be logged as an error in your console!

Comment: Thanks @PeterVR. In the Chrome console, I'm getting a 404 not found for the gettheme.php url (the url exists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mistyped the function syntax use as `function(){`
I just tried an example to show you the usage

```js
$('#subject').change(function(){
    var v = $(this).val();
    if(v==1)
     $('#theme').val(2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="subject">
  <option value='0'>Select</option>
  <option value='1'>1</option>
  <option value='2'>2</option>
</select>
<select id="theme">
  <option value='1'>1</option>
  <option value='2'>2</option>
</select>
I tried this, which is not working. Any help ?
```

Comment: Thanks @Tushar, the idea is, when I select a value in #subject, I get the corresponding value, 1 or 2 and send that as a variable to fetch a page using ajax, where, I run a query and make the new options based on that.

Comment: I see what you mean, thanks, right there was a typo there. I fixed that and getting the alert now. The Ajax is still not loading :)

Comment: Yes, a bunch of options, like 
`<option value="">Select theme</option>
<option value="">Aucun theme</option>`

Comment: Please just show your php code...I jst have to check :)

Comment: Hi @Tushar, that Console checking did the trick, there was another typo in the url and hence the page was not loading :) Thanks for all your time :)

Answer (score 1):

jquery fixed. Its working in my server.

**Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#subject').change(function(){
   var v = $(this).val();
    getTheme(v);
});
});
function getTheme(id) {
    alert(id);
   $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "gettheme.php",
     data: "q=" + id, 
     success: function(data) {
          $('#theme').html(data);
     }
   });
}
```